# How to change values in a select box with options in checkbox when clicked on another select box options

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a html select box with options given in checkbox

```html
<select id="chk1" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
             <option value="1">Option 1</option>
             <option value="2">Option 2</option>
             <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select> 
    if i clicked on option 1 ,I want to change the values of another checkbox based on the click.
     <select id="chk2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
             <option value="1">Option 1</option>
             <option value="2">Option 2</option>
             <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

how is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `$('.first').val( $('.second').val())` and reverse.

If you want only that `select#1` can change `select#2`

See this Demo:

```js
$('.first').on('change', function() {
    $('.second').val($(this).val());
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;  
}

select option {
  padding: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<br>

<select class="first" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>


<select class="second" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

**Generic Version with reserve change values**

EDIT: Updated you can now add more `<select>` boxes. Code is now more generic.

```js
// if you have only two select and do something between the operation is this the more clean solution. But yes, you can do all in one onChange function if you make out which one is actually "changing" (see below)
$('.first').on('change', function() {
    $('.second').val($(this).val());
});

$('.second').on('change', function() {
    $('.first').val($(this).val());
});


// for any count of select
$('select').on('change', function() {
    $('select').not(this).val($(this).val());
});


// code for testing only
$('button').click(function() {
  $('body').append($('select').first().clone());
  
  $('select').off('change').on('change', function() {
    $('select').not(this).val($(this).val());
  });
  
  $('select').trigger('change');
});
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;  
}

select option {
  padding: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Add another select</button><br>

<select class="first" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>


<select class="second" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply with simple javascript. Match value one with another

```js
function run(){

    document.getElementById("chk2").value=document.getElementById("chk1").value
  
  }
```

```html
<select id="chk1" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" onchange="run()">
             <option value="1">Option 1</option>
             <option value="2">Option 2</option>
             <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select> 
    if i clicked on option 1 ,I want to change the values of another checkbox based on the click.
     <select id="chk2" multiple="multiple" class="form-control">
             <option value="1">Option 1</option>
             <option value="2">Option 2</option>
             <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use multiple `$('.first, .second')` with `not(this)`

```
$('.first, .second').on('change', function() {
    $('select').not(this).val($(this).val());
});
```

**Alternate,**

```
$('.first, .second').on('change', function() {
   $(this).attr('class') == 'first' ? $('.second').val($(this).val()) : $('.first').val($(this).val())
});
```

FYI, instead of `select` selector you can also define common classes for respective `select tags`

```js
$('.first, .second').on('change', function() {
    $('select').not(this).val($(this).val());
});

/*$('.first, .second').on('change', function() {
  $(this).attr('class') == 'first' ? $('.second').val($(this).val()) : $('.first').val($(this).val()) 
});*/
```

```css
select {
  width: 100px;  
}

select option {
  padding: 5px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class="first" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>


<select class="second" multiple="multiple">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add the jQuery plugin to your page**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Add the jQuery code to your page**

```
<script>
    $('#chk1').on('change', function() {
        $('#chk2').val($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
<select class="first ddl" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<select class="second ddl" multiple="multiple">
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $('.ddl').on('change', function () {
        $('.ddl').not($(this)).val($(this).val());
    });
</script>
```